# remove rows from dataframe using for loop

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, dplyr

I have a dataframe (~1M rows) in which I would like to remove observations based on a condition.  Some example data is below

```
 irm     id          state.h state.j
 201403 113310E126       1       1
 201404 113310E126       1       1
 201405 113310E126       1       1
 201406 113310E126       1       1
 201407 113310E126       1       1
 201408 113310E126       1       1
 201409 113310E126       1       1
 201410 113310E126       1       1
 201411 113310E126       1       1
 201412 113310E126       1       1
 201501 113310E126       1       1
 201502 113310E126       1       1
 201503 113310E126       1       1
 201504 113310E126       1       1
 201505 113310E126       1       1
 201506 113310E126       1       1
 201507 113310E126       1       1
 201508 113310E126       1       1
 201509 113310E126       1       1
 201510 113310E126       1       1
 201511 113310E126       1       1
 201512 113310E126       1       1
 201601 113310E126       1       1
 201602 113310E126       1       1
 201603 113310E126       1       1
 201604 113310E126       1       1
 201605 113310E126       1       1
 201606 113310E126       1       1
 201607 113310E126       1       1
 201608 113310E126       1       1
 201609 113310E126       1       1
 201610 113310E126       1       1
 201611 113310E126       1       1
 201612 113310E126       1       1
 201701 113310E126       1       1
 201702 113310E126       1       1
 201703 113310E126       1       1
 201704 113310E126       1       1
 201705 113310E126       1       1
 201706 113310E126       1       1
 201707 113310E126       1       1
 201708 113310E126       1       1
 201709 113310E126       1       1
 201710 113310E126       1       1
 201711 113310E126       1       1
 201712 113310E126       1       1
 201801 113310E126       1       1
 201802 113310E126       1       1
 201803 113310E126       1       1
 201804 113310E126       1       1
 201805 113310E126       1       1
 201806 113310E126       1       1
 201807 113310E126       1       1
 201808 113310E126       1       1
 201809 113310E126       1       1
 201810 113310E126       1       1
 201811 113310E126       1       1
 201812 113310E126       1       1
 201901 113310E126       1       1
 201902 113310E126       1       1
 201903 113310E126       1       1
 201904 113310E126       1       1
 201905 113310E126       1       1
 201906 113310E126       1       1
 201907 113310E126       1       1
 201908 113310E126       1       1
 201909 113310E126       1       1
 201910 113310E126       1       1
 201911 113310E126       1       1
 201912 113310E126       1       1
 202001 113310E126       1       1
 202002 113310E126       1       1
 202003 113310E126       1       1
 202004 113310E126       1       1
 202005 113310E126       1       1
 202006 113310E126       1       1
 202007 113310E126       1       1
 202008 113310E126       1       1
 202009 113310E126       1       1
 202010 113310E126       1       1
 202011 113310E126       1       1
 202012 113310E126       1       1
 202101 113310E126       1       1
 202102 113310E126       1       1
 202103 113310E126       1       1
 202104 113310E126       1       1
 202105 113310E126       1       1
 202106 113310E126       1       1
 202107 113310E126       1       1
 202108 113310E126       1       1
 202109 113310E126       1       1
 202110 113310E126       1       1
 202111 113310E126       1       1
 202112 113310E126       1       1
 202201 113310E126       1       1
 202202 113310E126       1       1
 202203 113310E126       1       1
 202204 113310E126       1       1
 202205 113310E126       1       1
 202206 113310E126       1       5
 202207 113310E126       5       5
 202208 113310E126       5       5
 202209 113310E126       5       5
 202210 113310E126       5       5
 202211 113310E126       5       5
 202212 113310E126       5       5
 202301 113310E126       5       5
 202302 113310E126       5       5
 202303 113310E126       5       5
 202304 113310E126       5       5
 202305 113310E126       5       5
 202306 113310E126       5       6
 202307 113310E126       6       5
 202308 113310E126       5       5
```

The larger dataframe has 10,000+ unique values of the `id` variable.  What I would like to do is remove all rows from the dataframe after `state.j == 6` is observed.

I've tried the following on the sample below and it works fine:

```
df <- df[df$irm <= df$irm[df$state.j == 6],]
```

However, when I try this on the full dataframe, `df_full`, I don't get the correct result, and I get the following message:

```
    Warning message:
In df_full$irm <= df_full$irm[df_full$state.j == 6] :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

My question:

For each unique value of `id`, how can I remove all rows after `state.j` equals 6.  So for the example data, I would drop the last two observations.  Any and all suggestions are welcome.  Is it possible with a `for` loop?  Thank you.

Comment: You mentioned the unique values of `id`, are you intending to do this per-group or data as a whole?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `dplyr` using `group_by(id)`.  You want to identify the first time `state.j == 6`, which you could do with `min(which(state.j == 6))`.  Then you want to keep all rows up to that number:

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
df <- read.table(text="irm     id          state.h state.j
201403 113310E126       1       1
201404 113310E126       1       1
201405 113310E126       1       1
201406 113310E126       1       1
201407 113310E126       1       1
201408 113310E126       1       1
201409 113310E126       1       1
201410 113310E126       1       1
201411 113310E126       1       1
201412 113310E126       1       1
201501 113310E126       1       1
201502 113310E126       1       1
201503 113310E126       1       1
201504 113310E126       1       1
201505 113310E126       1       1
201506 113310E126       1       1
201507 113310E126       1       1
201508 113310E126       1       1
201509 113310E126       1       1
201510 113310E126       1       1
201511 113310E126       1       1
201512 113310E126       1       1
201601 113310E126       1       1
201602 113310E126       1       1
201603 113310E126       1       1
201604 113310E126       1       1
201605 113310E126       1       1
201606 113310E126       1       1
201607 113310E126       1       1
201608 113310E126       1       1
201609 113310E126       1       1
201610 113310E126       1       1
201611 113310E126       1       1
201612 113310E126       1       1
201701 113310E126       1       1
201702 113310E126       1       1
201703 113310E126       1       1
201704 113310E126       1       1
201705 113310E126       1       1
201706 113310E126       1       1
201707 113310E126       1       1
201708 113310E126       1       1
201709 113310E126       1       1
201710 113310E126       1       1
201711 113310E126       1       1
201712 113310E126       1       1
201801 113310E126       1       1
201802 113310E126       1       1
201803 113310E126       1       1
201804 113310E126       1       1
201805 113310E126       1       1
201806 113310E126       1       1
201807 113310E126       1       1
201808 113310E126       1       1
201809 113310E126       1       1
201810 113310E126       1       1
201811 113310E126       1       1
201812 113310E126       1       1
201901 113310E126       1       1
201902 113310E126       1       1
201903 113310E126       1       1
201904 113310E126       1       1
201905 113310E126       1       1
201906 113310E126       1       1
201907 113310E126       1       1
201908 113310E126       1       1
201909 113310E126       1       1
201910 113310E126       1       1
201911 113310E126       1       1
201912 113310E126       1       1
202001 113310E126       1       1
202002 113310E126       1       1
202003 113310E126       1       1
202004 113310E126       1       1
202005 113310E126       1       1
202006 113310E126       1       1
202007 113310E126       1       1
202008 113310E126       1       1
202009 113310E126       1       1
202010 113310E126       1       1
202011 113310E126       1       1
202012 113310E126       1       1
202101 113310E126       1       1
202102 113310E126       1       1
202103 113310E126       1       1
202104 113310E126       1       1
202105 113310E126       1       1
202106 113310E126       1       1
202107 113310E126       1       1
202108 113310E126       1       1
202109 113310E126       1       1
202110 113310E126       1       1
202111 113310E126       1       1
202112 113310E126       1       1
202201 113310E126       1       1
202202 113310E126       1       1
202203 113310E126       1       1
202204 113310E126       1       1
202205 113310E126       1       1
202206 113310E126       1       5
202207 113310E126       5       5
202208 113310E126       5       5
202209 113310E126       5       5
202210 113310E126       5       5
202211 113310E126       5       5
202212 113310E126       5       5
202301 113310E126       5       5
202302 113310E126       5       5
202303 113310E126       5       5
202304 113310E126       5       5
202305 113310E126       5       5
202306 113310E126       5       6
202307 113310E126       6       5
202308 113310E126       5       5", header=TRUE)
```

```r
newdf <- df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  filter(row_number() <= min(which(state.j == 6)))

tail(newdf)
#> # A tibble: 6 × 4
#> # Groups:   id [1]
#>      irm       id state.h state.j
#>    <int>    <dbl>   <int>   <int>
#> 1 202301 1.13e131       5       5
#> 2 202302 1.13e131       5       5
#> 3 202303 1.13e131       5       5
#> 4 202304 1.13e131       5       5
#> 5 202305 1.13e131       5       5
#> 6 202306 1.13e131       5       6
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

@DaveArmstrong's dplyr solution is a good one (and the first), here are alternatives:

## base R

```r
out <- df[ave(df$state.j == 6, df$id, FUN = function(z) cumsum(z) < 1),]
tail(out)
#        irm         id state.h state.j
# 106 202212 113310E126       5       5
# 107 202301 113310E126       5       5
# 108 202302 113310E126       5       5
# 109 202303 113310E126       5       5
# 110 202304 113310E126       5       5
# 111 202305 113310E126       5       5
```

## dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  filter(!cumany(state.j == 6), .by = id)
```

(The `.by=` requires a recent dplyr, otherwise use `group_by(id) %>% filter(!cumany(..))`.)

## data.table

```r
library(data.table)
as.data.table(df)[, .SD[cumsum(state.j == 6) < 1,], by = .(id)]
```

---

Data

```r
df <- structure(list(irm = c("201403", "201404", "201405", "201406", "201407", "201408", "201409", "201410", "201411", "201412", "201501", "201502", "201503", "201504", "201505", "201506", "201507", "201508", "201509", "201510", "201511", "201512", "201601", "201602", "201603", "201604", "201605", "201606", "201607", "201608", "201609", "201610", "201611", "201612", "201701", "201702", "201703", "201704", "201705", "201706", "201707", "201708", "201709", "201710", "201711", "201712", "201801", "201802",  "201803", "201804", "201805", "201806", "201807", "201808", "201809", "201810", "201811", "201812", "201901", "201902", "201903", "201904", "201905", "201906", "201907", "201908", "201909", "201910", "201911", "201912", "202001", "202002", "202003", "202004", "202005", "202006", "202007", "202008", "202009", "202010", "202011", "202012", "202101", "202102", "202103", "202104", "202105", "202106", "202107", "202108", "202109", "202110", "202111", "202112", "202201", "202202", "202203", "202204", "202205",  "202206", "202207", "202208", "202209", "202210", "202211", "202212", "202301", "202302", "202303", "202304", "202305", "202306", "202307", "202308"), id = c("113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126",  "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126",  "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126",  "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126", "113310E126"), state.h = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L), state.j = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -114L))
```

Comment: what does the `.SD` do for the `data.table`?

Comment: it's a `S`ubset of the current/visible `D`ata. (It will be all data for a single `id`. Internally it will iterate over each `id` and each `.SD` will be the subset of the whole.) Frankly, if you aren't already familiar with `data.table` nomenclature, I don't recommend jumping into it just for this. There are many legitimate reasons to shifting processes over to `data.table` but this is (simple) operation is not one of them. Go with what you are more comfortable with.

Comment: Thanks for `cumany()` @r2evans, that's one I always forget about.